# How to add TipAttribute to Model for MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a new attribute TipAttribute that I can use to display helpful tips to my users.

```cs
public class EditPersonModel {
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    [Tip(Message = "Enter the person's full name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So from my View I would do

```cs
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.InputFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TipFor(m => m.Name)
</div>
```

and it would render

```xml
<div class="editor-field">
    <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">
    <div class="tip">Enter the person's full name.</div>
</div>
```

I know that I would need to write an Extension method for HtmlHelper, but I have no idea what should go inside!

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString TipFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) {
    ???
}
```

I've started looking at the implementation of DisplayAttribute within Mvc3 Source Code, but it's very complex and doesn't look like providing my own custom attribute is very easy/pluggable. Is there a standard MVC3-way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your tip attribute was made metadata aware:

```
public class TipAttribute: Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["tip"] = Message;
    }
}
```

you could:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString TipFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
    ) 
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var tip = metaData.AdditionalValues["tip"] as string;
        var div = new TagBuilder("div");
        div.AddCssClass("tip");
        div.SetInnerText(tip ?? string.Empty);
        return new HtmlString(div.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I haven't tested yet, but this makes perfect sense and this is what I was hoping for... a system like IMetadataAware that lets me extend the built-in Lambda parser.